# What is an appropriate model for detecting CPU usage abnormality?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I am currently working on a model for detecting CPU usage abnormality for our regression test cases. The goal is to keep tracking the CPU usage day after day, and raise an alarm if the CPU usage of any particular test case rockets up so that the relevant developer can kick in in time for investigation.

The model I've figured out is like this:

1. Measure the CPU usage of the target process every second. Just read the /proc/#pid/stat and make the #CPU time# divided by the #wall time# during the passed second (which means the #wall time# must be 1).
2. When the test case finishes, we get an array of CPU usage data (how long the array is depends on how long the test case runs). Go through this array and get a summary array with 5 elements, which represents the distribution of CPU usage --  [0~20%, 20~40%, 40~60%, 60~80%, +80%], such as [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1].

   - 0~20%: How many measurements over the total measurements have CPU usage between 0 and 20%
   - 20~40%: How many measurements over the total measurements have CPU usage between 20% and 40%
   - 40~60%: How many measurements over the total measurements have CPU usage between 40% and 60%
   - 60~80%: How many measurements over the total measurements have CPU usage between 60% and 80%
   - +80%:   How many measurements over the total measurements have CPU usage over 80% (actually the CPU usage might be higher than 100% if multi-threading is enabled)

   The sum of this summary array should be 1.
3. Then I do calculation on the summary array and get a score with this formula:

   ```
   summary[0]*1 + summary[1]*1 + summary[2]*2 + summary[3]*4 + summary[4]*8
   ```

   The principle is: higher CPU usage gets higher penalty.
4. The higher the final score is, the higher the overall CPU usage is. For any particular test case, I can get one score every day. If the score rockets up some day, an alarm is raised.

To verify this model, I've repeatedly run a randomly selected set of test cases for a few hundred times, on different machines. I found that on any particular host, the scores fluctuate, but within a reasonable range. However, different hosts live in different ranges.

This is a diagram showing the scores of 600 runs for a particular test case. Different colors indicate different hosts.

[image]

Here are a few questions:

- Does it make sense that the scores on different machines locate in different ranges?
- If I want to trace CPU usage for a test case, should I run it merely on one dedicated machine day after day?
- Is there any better model for tracing CPU usage and raising alarms?

Comment: Is CPU usage a good metric? Is high CPU usage a problem? If you think about it, CPUs are supposed to be used--that's why we have them! Any time the CPU is idle is wasted time. I suspect you're measuring CPU usage because it's easy to measure, not because high CPU usage is fundamentally a bad thing.

Comment: What you're really trying to detect are logic errors such as infinite loops. Keep in mind (a) CPU usage doesn't tell you if the program is buggy or is performing valuable calculations. There is high likelihood for noise and false positives. (b) There are many, many other types of logic errors. Why detect this one type this way? I think you'll have more success with targeted testing strategies such as unit tests, integration tests, sim/stim, fuzz testing, etc.

Comment: Detecting CPU usage abnormality comes from a bug a developer once introduced, which led to 100% CPU usage forever and our product becoming sluggish. The goal is to detect this sort of unexpected bugs.

Answer (score -1):

You should have an O(n) model for every function based on what you believe it should be doing.  Then generate your regression cases against it by having variations on n.  If the function does not display expected performance as n increases, something is wrong.  If it is too good, the problem is in your expectations and test cases.

Another approach is to come up with a theoretical ideal run metric.  These tend to save time via hard coding or looking up in massive tables.  Here, additional error checking, etc required will detract from your efficiency compared to the ideal run method.

Only way to prove cpu use is bad is to come up with a better alternative.  If you could do so, then you should have designed your dev process to produce the better algorithm in the first place!